# Offline installation for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

I need to install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 on a system that has no Internet connection. However, when I download the offline installer and run it, it shows a "downloading required files" dialog box.

Why am I seeing this message, and how do I get it to install offline?